# AutoCompleteExtender position is wrong in Webkit

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I have an ajaxtoolkit AutoCompleteExtender that has position: absolute. I have placed it inside a div with position: relative. This makes the extender dropdown place itself perfectly on all browsers, except on Chrome/Safari, where the position is relative to the top left of the window instead of the div.

When I place another ul with the same css class and inline style as the HTML that is generated for the AutoCompleteExtender, the positioning works fine in Chrome. So there is something specific to the extender that makes it render at the bottom of the HTML code (just before the  end tag, and therefore not using the div as it's parent when calculating its position.

Any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Code:

```
<div class="searching">
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
            runat="server" 
            ID="biznameOrCategoryAutoComplete" 
            TargetControlID="txtBizNameOrCategory"
            ServicePath="~/AutoComplete.asmx"
            ServiceMethod="GetBiznameOrCategoryCompletionList"
            MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
            CompletionInterval="1000"
            EnableCaching="true"
            CompletionSetCount="10" 
            CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionCompyNameListElement" 
            CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" 
            CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
            ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
        </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.searching {
margin-left:5px;
padding-top:10px;
width:366px;
position: relative;
}
.autocomplete_completionCompyNameListElement {
background: #fff;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
width: 340px !important;
left: 20px !important;
border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
font-size: 12px;
top: 48px !important;
padding: 2px 4px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add plain HTML `<div>` element right after extender with spcified `id` attribute and use this `id` value for extender's `CompletionListElementID` property.

When you pass an `id` to the extender it will insert the items as `<div>` elements. So adding a plain HTML `<div>` rather than a `<ul>` maintains valid HTML.

Comment: Hey im having the same problem with this extenders position in ie i tried todo what you suggested but there is no difference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288125/autocompleteextender-position-is-wrong-not-directly-under-textbox

Comment: When you pass an id to `CompletionListElementID` the items that are inserted into that element are divs. I have edited your answer to suggest inserting a `<div>` instead of a `<ul>` to maintain valid HTML