# AutoCompleteExtender position is wrong not directly under textbox

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

My AutoCompleteExtender works except that the extender is in the wrong position it's to far down 
i tried this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338855/autocompleteextender-position-is-wrong-in-webkit) but it didn't work this is in ie browser

```
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Email">Email</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="UserName">User Name</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                       </td>
                        <td>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TxtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoComplete1" runat="server" BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx"
                    TargetControlID="TxtSearch" ServicePath="~/CMSWebServices/MemberService.asmx" ServiceMethod="SearchUsersByName"
                    MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionInterval="500" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="12" CompletionListElementID="TxtSearchPosition">
                </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>   
                <ul id="TxtSearchPosition"></ul>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                 <asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: it should be the problem related to css ...

Comment: I solved it no worries. I had to wrap a div around the AutoCompleteExtender

Comment: Hi! I am facing the same issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416573/ajax-auto-complete-extender-ie9-wrong-display-positon) in IE9. Could you please suggest me how to solve it? Thanks a lot!